# Hardware encryption on usb drive / stick

Tags: linux, usb, encryption, raspberry-pi, decryption

I am wondering whether there is a possibility to encrypt and decrypt an usb drive or stick with some microcontroller or single-board computer (e.g. Raspberry Pi) on the fly.

For instance I want to encrypt my usb drive, connect it to my tv and watch movies. My tv does not support decryption so I need a device between my drive and tv.

Would be handy if I can use a Raspberry Pi for this purpose. Any suggestions?

Comment: Might be better to use the Pi as a *network* file host in that situation, then stream over DLNA or similar.

Comment: @pjc50 sure that's possible but the TV was just an example. What is if there is no network option? My intention is more that it is portable to as many devices as possible. The most devices have an USB port

Answer (score 2):

USB distinguishes between hosts (i.e. your computer) and devices (e.g. a mouse, a USB drive, a webcam). These are normally not exchangeable (for exceptions see below). Most x86 computers support only working in host mode.

Your use case requires both -- host support to connect to your USB drive and device support to connect to your TV.

Single-board computers often do support device mode (if a USB port is switchable between host and device mode, it's often labeled as "USB OTG").

In the Raspberry universe, the model A and the Zero seem to support USB OTG (https://learn.adafruit.com/turning-your-raspberry-pi-zero-into-a-usb-gadget/overview), but they have only one USB port, so you can't use them in your use case.

Other SBCs that support device mode and have more than one USB port are e.g. the BeagleBoard (at least the models "Green" and "Black rev C") and the CubieBoard (at least CB 3 (aka CubieTruck), perhaps also other models) and the Odroid C2.

Another point to consider is if the SBC is able to en/decrypt fast enough.

The software part is then straight-forward:

- mount USB drive and setup device encryption

  caveat: How do you plan to handle the encryption keys? Attach a keyboard and screen to the SBC?
- export the decrypted file system as a USB block device. The linux kernel calls USB device mode "USB gadget mode" and includes a driver that exports a file or a block device as a USB storage device.

Comment: Thanks for that answer! Maybe I use a biometric sensor for the keys. I want to build a portable device to encrypt and decrypt any devices

Comment: You could also add a touch screen for user interface and password entry.